# PHP: filter_input_array with default argument

Tags: php, sanitization

I try to create universal sanitize solution for POST inputs, because I'm very paranoid. I want to sanitize each value in POST array based on arguments, but when arg's key is not defined, use some universal filter type (e.g. FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING). So far, I use this simple loop (PHP 7) with filter_input function:

```
$args = array(
    'user_id' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
    'email' => FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL,
    ...
);

$clean = array();

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $clean[$key] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $key, $args[$key] ?? FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}
```

I'm not sure if this solution is 'good enough' and I wonder if I can set default filter type for function `filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);` because POST sometimes can contain array?